# Increment negative number displayed for Queue Size field in the Member Clients Table

Tags: gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

After enabling subscription conflate in my regions, I saw increment negative number (-XXXXX) in the queue size field in the Member Client Table in GemFire Pulse Website. Any reason that the negative number appear in the queue size field?

- GemFire Version : 9.8.6
- Number of Regions : 1
- 1 Client Application updating regions every 0.5 seconds (Caching Proxy)
- 1 Client Application reading data from regions (Caching Proxy - Register interest for all keys)
- 1 Locators and 1 Cache Server in same virtual machine

Queue Size. The size of the queue used by server to send events in case of a subscription enabled client or a client that has continuous queries running on the server. [https://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/910/geode/developing/events/tune_client_message_tracking_timeout.html].

**Additional Discovery**

Pulse Website (Negative Number in Queue Size)

[image]

JConsole (showClientQueueDetail)

(numVoidRemovals (4486)

[image]

[image]

```
@ClientCacheApplication(locators = {
@ClientCacheApplication.Locator(host = "192.168.208.20", port = 10311) }, name = "Reading-Testing", subscriptionEnabled = true)
@EnableEntityDefinedRegions(basePackageClasses = Person.class, clientRegionShortcut = ClientRegionShortcut.CACHING_PROXY, poolName = "SecondPool")
@EnableGemfireRepositories(basePackageClasses = PersonRepository.class)
@EnablePdx
@Import({ GemfireCommonPool.class })
public class PersonDataAccess {
  ....
}

@Configuration
public class GemfireCommonPool {

@Bean("SecondPool")
public Pool init() {
    PoolFactory poolFactory = PoolManager.createFactory();
    poolFactory.setPingInterval(8000);
    poolFactory.setRetryAttempts(-1);
    poolFactory.setMaxConnections(-1);
    poolFactory.setReadTimeout(30000);
    poolFactory.addLocator("192.168.208.20", 10311);
    poolFactory.setSubscriptionEnabled(true);
    return poolFactory.create("SecondPool");
}
```

}

**Additonal Discovery 2**

When i remove the poolName field in @EnableEntityDefinedRegions, I found out that the pulse website does not display negative number for the queue size. However, in the showClientQueueDetail, it display negative number for queue size.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Is it my coding error or conflate issue?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Hello Jack, it might be that the `MBean` is returning an invalid value or that the actual value is too large and the internal `Integer` used to store this information has overflowed, I can't tell for sure from just the description... would you be able to open a ticket within the [Geode Jira Project](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/GEODE) and attach the relevant artefacts (logs, `pulse` print screen, reproducible scenario if you have one, etc.).

Comment: When I removed the subscription conflate in the cache server XML, it is back to normal (no have negative number). So I suspect it is subscription conflate setting.. Also, the negative number occured when I immediately start the application.. The positive integer range is to 2147483647. So I think should no be the case that the actual value is greater than internal Integer. I try to see whether I can reproducible the scenario at home then open a ticket. Do you know which MBean ?

Comment: Hello Jack, I believe the `MXBean` used is `CacheServerMXBean`, specifically the `showAllClientStats` and `showClientQueueDetails` methods.

Comment: Hi @JuanRamos , Is it my coding error or conflate issue? Is it normal that a application has two subscriptions (two queue detail- different port number)?